# Maximum odd number of subsets, each intersects exactly half of the others

Tags: combinatorics, combinatorial-geometry, extremal-combinatorics

Find the largest positive integer $k$ with the following property $-$ there exist $2k+1$ distinct subsets of $\{1,\ldots,20\}$ such that each such subset intersects precisely $k$ of the other $2k$ subsets.

The original problem I saw also insisted on each set to have $7$ elements (which makes things much easier $-$ it is easy to obtain $k\leq 2$) but what would happen if the do not have such a restriction?

I cannot obtain anything apart from the fact that $k$ is even (since the number of intersecting pairs is $\frac{k(2k+1)}{2}$). Any help appreciated!

Comment: Easy enough to constructively show that k is at least $8 < (20 - 1)/2$: $\{1,2,3,4,5\}, \{2,3,4,5,6\}, \ldots,\{13,14,15,16,17\},\{14,15,16,17,1\},\ldots,\{17,1,2,3,4\}$

Comment: Consider a $5$ by $5$ array of squares. Choose an element and put a copy of it in each square across a row. Repeat for each row using a different element each time. Using a different element each time do the same for each column and then each of $5$ parallel diagonals (with wrap around). This uses  $15$ elements and gives $25$ distinct subsets such that each one intersects precisely $12$ others.

Comment: With $15$ elements I can get a collection of $225$ subsets with this property, corresponding to $k=112$.

Comment: On $7$ elements, taking all $2$-element subsets yields $k=10$, and it is not hard to verify that this is maximal. On $15$ elements, partitioning into a $5$- and $10$-element subset, taking all $3$-element subsets that contain precisely $1$ element from the $5$ and $2$ elements from the $10$ yields $k=112$. I don't know whether this is maximal.

Comment: This question received a bounty because experienced users drew attention to it in [the Pearl Dive](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102837/pearl-dive).

Comment: If you replace 20 with $n$, the maximum values of $k$ for $n=1,\dots,9$ are $0,0,0,0,2,4,10,10,10$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not an answer, but too long for a comment.

First, here's a graph-theoretic interpretation.  Define a graph with a node for each subset of $\{1,\dots,n\}$ and an edge for each pair of distinct nodes that have nonempty intersection. The problem is to find a largest subset $S$ of nodes such that both the subgraph induced by $S$ and its complement are $k$-regular.

Now here's an integer linear programming formulation.  Let $N_i$ be the set of neighbors of node $i$, and let $\overline{k}=(2^n-1)/2$ be an upper bound on integer decision variable $k$.  Let binary decision variable $x_i$ indicate whether node $i$ is selected.  The problem is to maximize $k$ subject to
\begin{align}
\sum_i x_i &= 2k+1\\
-\overline{k}(1-x_i) \le \sum_{j \in N_i} x_j - k &\le |N_i|(1-x_i) &\text{for all $i$}\\
k &\in [0, \overline{k}] \cap \mathbb{Z}
\end{align}
The first constraint specifies that $2k+1$ nodes are selected.  The second "big-M" constraint enforces the implication $x_i=1 \implies \sum_{j \in N_i} x_j = k$. That is, if node $i$ is selected then exactly $k$ of its neighbors are also selected.  The third constraint enforces bounds and integrality of $k$.  The optimal values reported above for $n\in\{1,\dots,9\}$ were obtained by solving this formulation.